# how to download redhat JBoss BRMS 6.2.0 GA

Tags: jboss, redhat, business-process-management

I want to download JBoss BRMS 6.2.0 GA i have visited.
http://developers.redhat.com/products/brms/download/
http://www.jboss.org/products/brms/download/

version 6.3.0, 6.1.0 and all other can be downloaded, but when click on installer6.2.0 it returns me a thank you page but nothing starts to download.

how - ***jboss-brms-6.2.0.GA-installer.jar*** - can be downloaded

Answer (score 1):

The links are woking fine and you can download v6.0.2 as well as other versions. 
There may be some maintenance because of which you was unable to download v6.0.2 but now you can download this version as well.